# Scilab 6.1.1 saving all local variables to file

Tags: scilab

I want to save all local variables in a file and next delete all variables and finally display a working directory

```
variables = who('local');
save("file",variables)
```

console output:

```
save: Unable to export variable 'Branchinglib' in file 'file'.
```

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing (please explain your problem) ?

Comment: I got an task from my professor to save all local variables to a file

Comment: `save file` without variable names argument will save all your user variables.